# How to remove metadata of mp3 file?

Tags: mp3, metadata, windows-media-player

I used Mp3tag software to remove metadata of some mp3 files, and it appears to work fine in Windows Media Player: the name of the artist, song, cover, etc.

But if I play the entire album, suddenly in the penultimate song the previous non-cover, erroneous artist metadata appears and all the songs gets corrupted too. I close WMP and check all the metadata in Mp3tag: it appears to be correct. I play this particular song alone in WMP: the metadata are fine. Then I play the entire album and volia: the penultimate song has the erroneous metadata and this happens all over again.

Repeat:

1. The metadata of each song is correct
   in Mp3tag.
2. The metadata of each song is correct in WMP if played alone.
3. The metadata gets corrupted in the penultimate song and spreads to others.

What is wrong? Some strange cache behavior in WMP? mp3tag is not doing a good job?

Comment: Are there any non-ASCII characters in any of the songs?

Comment: This might be more related to Windows Media Player than the MP3 file. Have you checked for dodgy album art in the folder in which the files are stored? Have you tried stripping the tags with another tool, or in Windows Media Player itself? Have a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/massid3lib/ for another tag editor.

Comment: @Ignacio: Just ASCII characters.

Comment: @Randolph: thanks for the suggestions. I will try another tag editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect Mp3Tag. Try [ID3 Kill](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/12/21/id3-tag-remover/).

[image]

Comment: Hope that helps...

Answer (score 2):

If Mp3tag lets you choose the tag version, make sure it is ID3 **v2.3**: Windows Media Player doesn't yet support 2.4 completely.

Comment: tags are v2.3.

Answer (score 1):

You could use eye3D, a Python app. If your OS supports Python, then you can use it. Please follow the link to discover how to install it.

`eyeD3 --remove-all <FILE_PATH>`. [Docs here](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/classic_plugin.html).

Comment: While this may barely answer the question, it lacks the context required to make it a good answer. What is eyeD3? Does it work on Windows computers? Please use the EDIT button to add relevant and expanding information to your answer so that it becomes actually helpful.

Comment: You have to spend two seconds clicking on the link to discover it. I'd agree if I hadn't put it.

Comment: That's not how SU works. Please read the Help section, particularly the bits about good answers. A good answer CAN have a link, but it should not be necessary to open the link in order to fully grasp the answer as it pertains to the given question.

Answer (score 0):

BatchPurifier can also remove metadata of MP3 files (ID3v1, ID3v2, APE)

Answer (score 0):

This will not remove any data entered into the "Extra metadata" tags such as Compilation, Lyrics, ISRC, Work, etc.

### HOW TO REMOVE ALL METADATA FROM MP3 FILES

My suggestion to remove all metadata and add your own is to:

1. Open the MP3 file in an Audio Editor app (Audacity)
2. Save it as a Wave File in a new Folder:   Export as WAV...
3. Close the File (File -> Close)
4. Close Audacity
5. Open the new Wave File in Sound Forge(another Audio Editor)
6. Save as an MP3 File (Save as type: MP3 Audio (*.mp3):

   - Make sure "Save metadata with file" is Checked
   - Click on "Custom..."
   - At the bottom of the new Window that appears Click on the "ID3 Settings" Tab
   - Make sure "Save both ID3 version 1 and version 2 tags to file" is Checked
   - Enter all your own Metadata into the Tags
   - Click OK.
   - Click Save.
   - Close the File.
7. Close the Audio Editor(Sound Forge)
8. Play the new MP3 File in a Media Player(VLC Media Player)

   - Click the "Tools" Tab
   - Click on "Media Information"
   - Check out all the Metadata. It has only the metadata that you entered into it.